# Why does IE 11 ignore my CSS3 multiple background images code?

Tags: image, css, background, internet-explorer-11

Ok, so im using CSS3 to implement two different background images on my website http://portfolio.yoursitedesigned.com/index.php. It works fine in every other browser except for opera (latest) and IE 11 and i cant figure out why. I read a couple of similar questions but none of the answers solve my problem. Here is my CSS code.

My most recent attempt:

```
background:url(images/background.png) no-repeat top center, url(images/bgbottom.png) repeat-x bottom center, #e5decf;
```

My first attempt:

```
background-image:url(images/background.png), url(images/bgbottom.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat, repeat-x;
background-position:top center, bottom center;
background-color:#e5decf;
```

Both will show the colour in IE 11 and the first image but not the second image.

Anyone can tell me why?

Comment: It's working for me (Windows 7)

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in IE11 and Opera 12.10 on Win7

Comment: It seems to me IE11 screws up calculating the height of your content. You could try removing `float:left` (which is set on every element on your whole site). In addition you can try setting `html,body{height:100%}`, and set the container elements to `height:100%`.

Answer (score 0):

Often IE is picky on syntax when other browsers are a bit forgiving.

I think the background-position may not be right. The **first** value is the **horizontal** position and the **second** value is the **vertical**.

Try changing to this:

```
background-position:center top, center bottom;
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: IE has not had any trouble with this as far as I know. When both values are keywords, they can appear in any order so long as one is horizontal and the other is vertical.